# How to embed Facebook videos?

Tags: nodes, media, wysiwyg

-Drupal 7.37 & Omega4-Subtheme

-Windows7 HP & Toshiba Laptop

-Acquia-DevDesktop WAMP-Stack

-Latest Wysiwyg, CKEditor & Media_Module & Media_Oembed

1. Now I have tried everything and nothing allows a Facebook Video to Embed.
2. I have tried using the Facebook-URI/Embed-Code in the Media_Module-Media-Browser as well as dropping the Facebook-Embed-Code (using cut-and-paste) in the text-area.  The Facebook-Embed-Code that Facebook gives you, BTW seems strange to me.
3. Oembed (not the Media_Oembed Module) did not work at all.
4. Tried using another Wysiwyg-Rich-Text-Editor, besides CKEditor, because CKEditor strips out code and that switch did not help make the Videos embed.
5. Tried editing the CKEditor Advanced-Content-Filter to stop it from rewiring any code and that did not help.
6. The Video-Lightbox Software application seems to refuse the Facebook URI's also.
7. Media_Oembed also fails to help Media_Module to recognize Facebook-Embeds or URI's.
8. When I just cut-and-paste the Facebook-Embed-Code directly into a basic HTML-Document outside of Drupal (and even outside of a WAMP-Stack), this also does not work.  Viewing the source-code in FireFox, again I see some of the Facebook-Embed-Code is missing, having been stripped out by something.  What? FireFox?  HTML5?  This is the most puzzling.  Maybe the WAMP-Stack is necessary for embeds, but the link works.
9. Something seems to be removing part of the Code or else Facebook is using bad code inadvertently, being unaware of some configuration in the outside world.
10. Basically the URI's just deliver a red-reject-box from the Media_Module-Browser or else they deliver an iFrame or Flash that is dead in the water. Direct cut-and-pastes deliver just direct unprocessed raw code on output or else just, oddly, a link to the Facebook-Page that shows the name of the Video's owner and nothing more.
11. Any thought from anyone?  I am just really interested if anyone out there is embedding Facebook-Videos in ANY kind of way and if so, how?

Comment: I think FB changed the structure of its video embeds a couple of months ago, maybe the contrib modules haven't caught up yet

Comment: Somehow did not see this reply, and I am beginning to think that Facebook is doing something odd.  When I get some free time I am going to explore different browsers to see if this some kind of browser issue.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and paste it in the textarea, make sure you have full HTML filter selected, if y do not have that option, go to Text format and create a filter

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have been doing that already.